# Wrap equations just like normal text

Tags: formatting

I am trying to write an APA style paragraph with equations in the paragraph, however LaTeX seems to be deciding to try and keep the equation on a full line, instead of naturally wrapping on to the next line much like text would. Here is an example of how it looks now:

[image: example]

It should just wrap. Is there an automatic way to just allow it to wrap just like any other text not in the `$$` signs?

Edit:

Here is my text including packages:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,man,natbib]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel} \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{breqn}

$F(3,36) = 14.017, p < 0.001, n^2_{partial} = 0.539$. Specifically,
participants who were in the no perfume group ($M = 6.4, SE = 0.34$)
gave significantly higher ratings than participants who were in the No
Name ($M=3.4, SE=0.37$), $q(3,36) = 8.30, p < 0.01, d = 2.67$,
PopStar($M=3.7, SE = 0.33$), $q(3,36) = 7.47, p < 0.01, d = 5.53$, or
MovieStar($M=4.3, SE = 0.40$), $q(3,36) = 5.81, p < 0.01, d = 1.81$
groups.
```

This is a sample of my full paper, I hope that is enough.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you've used to generate the screenshot you posted.

Comment: Yes, formulas between $...$ will wrap, unless you put them in boxes, or you have some weird parameters set up. What's an APA style paragraph? Show your code.

Comment: I assume that `\raggedright` is applied in your document and that you write the "equations" as `NoName $(M=3.4, SE=0.37)$, $q(4,36)=7.47, p<0.01, d=2.67$`. Please confirm or disconfirm this hunch.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum hi welcome to the site:-)

Comment: @PietvanOostrum I am using the APA document class and writing and APA style format to report statistical analysis findings. That is what I meant.

Comment: @Mico I never wrote any `\raggedright` in my document, and a `CTRL + F` finds no such text written.

Comment: Welcome! :) For code, you should use the code sample markdown, instead of the block quote markdown (`>`). Simply highlight your code and hit crtl + k, or press the code sample button (the one that looks like {}) and then you can get syntax highlighting and whitespace will be preserved and all that goodness. As a small point, your MWE wasn't quite complete as you had missed out the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Not a major deal, but the gold standard is code that we can copy and paste into a file and render without doing anything else, and it will run, or show us your exact problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that your document uses `\raggedright` style rather than full justification *and* that you input the "equations" in the following format:

```
NoName $(M=3.4, SE=0.37)$, $q(4,36)=7.47, p<0.01, d=2.67$;
PopStar $(M=3.7, SE=0.33)$, $q(4,36)=8.30, p<0.01, d=5.53$; or
MovieStar $(M=4.3, SE=0.40)$, $q(4,36)=5.81, p<0.01, d=1.81$ groups.
```

See panel A. below, which pretty much manages to replicate the "look" of your screenshot. I will call this math style "long equations" style.

Assuming this hunch is correct, there are two remedies to consider:

- Use `\RaggedRight` (a macro provided by the `ragged2e` package) instead of `\raggedright`, and
- use "short" equations, i.e., write

  ```
  NoName ($M=3.4$, $SE=0.37$), $q(4,36)=7.47$, $p<0.01$, $d=2.67$;
  PopStar ($M=3.7$, $SE=0.33$), $q(4,36)=8.30$, $p<0.01$, $d=5.53$; or
  MovieStar ($M=4.3$, $SE=0.40$), $q(4,36)=5.81$, $p<0.01$, $d=1.81$ groups.
  ```

  Observe that there are now five rather than two equations per line. I certainly recommend the "short equations" style.

As panels B, C, and D below illustrate, you'll get much more satisfying output if you use one of the combinations of `\RaggedRight` and "short" equation style.

Panel E shows the "look" that's generated if (a) full justification is in effect and (b) short equations are used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext,ragged2e}
\usepackage[textwidth=5.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\noindent
\verb+A. \raggedright, "long" equations+

\noindent\raggedright
ratings $F(3.36)=14.017$, $p<0.001$, $n^2_{\text{partial}}=0.539$. Specifically, participants who were in the no perfume group ($M=6.4, SE=0.34$) gave significantly higher ratings than participants who were in the NoName $(M=3.4, SE=0.37)$, $q(4,36)=7.47, p<0.01, d=2.67$;
PopStar $(M=3.7, SE=0.33)$, $q(4,36)=8.30, p<0.01, d=5.53$; or
MovieStar $(M=4.3, SE=0.40)$, $q(4,36)=5.81, p<0.01, d=1.81$ groups.

\endgroup
\bigskip\bigskip
\begingroup
\noindent
\verb+B. \RaggedRight, "long" equations+

\noindent\RaggedRight
ratings $F(3.36)=14.017$, $p<0.001$, $n^2_{\text{partial}}=0.539$. Specifically, participants who were in the no perfume group ($M=6.4, SE=0.34$) gave significantly higher ratings than participants who were in the NoName $(M=3.4, SE=0.37)$, $q(4,36)=7.47, p<0.01, d=2.67$;
PopStar $(M=3.7, SE=0.33)$, $q(4,36)=8.30, p<0.01, d=5.53$; or
MovieStar $(M=4.3, SE=0.40)$, $q(4,36)=5.81, p<0.01, d=1.81$ groups.

\endgroup

\bigskip\bigskip
\begingroup

\noindent
\verb+C. \raggedright, "short" equations+

\raggedright
\noindent
ratings $F(3.36)=14.017$, $p<0.001$, $n^2_{\text{partial}}=0.539$. Specifically, participants who were in the no perfume group ($M=6.4$, $SE=0.34$) gave significantly higher ratings than participants who were in the NoName ($M=3.4$, $SE=0.37$), $q(4,36)=7.47$, $p<0.01$, $d=2.67$;
PopStar ($M=3.7$, $SE=0.33$), $q(4,36)=8.30$, $p<0.01$, $d=5.53$; or
MovieStar ($M=4.3$, $SE=0.40$), $q(4,36)=5.81$, $p<0.01$, $d=1.81$ groups.

\endgroup

\bigskip\bigskip
\begingroup
\noindent
\verb+D. \RaggedRight, "short" equations+

\noindent\RaggedRight
ratings $F(3.36)=14.017$, $p<0.001$, $n^2_{\text{partial}}=0.539$. Specifically, participants who were in the no perfume group ($M=6.4$, $SE=0.34$) gave significantly higher ratings than participants who were in the NoName ($M=3.4$, $SE=0.37$), $q(4,36)=7.47$, $p<0.01$, $d=2.67$;
PopStar ($M=3.7$, $SE=0.33$), $q(4,36)=8.30$, $p<0.01$, $d=5.53$; or
MovieStar ($M=4.3$, $SE=0.40$), $q(4,36)=5.81$, $p<0.01$, $d=1.81$ groups.

\endgroup
\bigskip\bigskip
\noindent
\verb+E. full justification, "short" equations+

\noindent
ratings $F(3.36)=14.017$, $p<0.001$, $n^2_{\text{partial}}=0.539$. Specifically, participants who were in the no perfume group ($M=6.4$, $SE=0.34$) gave significantly higher ratings than participants who were in the NoName ($M=3.4$, $SE=0.37$), $q(4,36)=7.47$, $p<0.01$, $d=2.67$;
PopStar ($M=3.7$, $SE=0.33$), $q(4,36)=8.30$, $p<0.01$, $d=5.53$; or 
MovieStar ($M=4.3$, $SE=0.40$), $q(4,36)=5.81$, $p<0.01$, $d=1.81$ groups.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Full justification with "long" equations gives almost the same output as with "short" equations.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum - Thanks. A serious downside of the "long" equations is that the spacing after the commas is simply wrong for the material at hand.

Comment: observe that with example B, using `\RaggedRight`, the spaces after the commas are narrower than the spaces around the equal signs and other signs of relation.  can't think of a better demonstration that "short" equations are more appropriate than "long" equations.

Comment: Thank you. I did not specifically change anything with the justifications, however I am using Overleaf.com for my editing and it may change things. I have a document class with `letterpaper,man,natbib {apa6}` and the `english/babel, utf8x/inputenc, amsmath, graphicx, breqn` packages. I ended up going with the short equation format you suggested as I was in a bit of a time crunch, however for the future I will look at the `RaggedRight` and hopefully figure out why the full justication was not happening.

Comment: @Mico I just added in the relevant latex for the paragraph displayed and the packages. Hopefully that helps you see what is happening.

Comment: @ComputerLocus - If the `apa6` document class is loaded with the option `man`, a `\raggedright` instruction is executed during the class loading stage. It may be a good idea to load the `ragged2e` package with the option `document`; that way, ragged-right rather than full justification will be in effect, but hyphenation and other reasonable line-breaking actions will be allowed.

Comment: @Mico I was using an APA LaTeX template, so I just never changed that document option. I have no problem with removing the `man` if that would fix the problem.

Comment: @ComputerLocus - Removing the `man` option will remove the automatic `\raggedright` mode; it will probably also change other formatting settings which you may or may not need. I have (obviously!) no knowledge of your document formatting needs. That said, I'd say that you should hesitate to use the `apa6` document class unless you plan to submit a paper to a journal that requires it.

Comment: @Mico only reason I am using the `apa6` document class is because for a psychology class I am required to write reports on some statistical analysis I do and it must be reported in the apa format. So I just thought using the apa6 format would be the best option. I only had the `man` option there as it was part of an APA style template I started with from Overleaf.

Comment: @ComputerLocus -  By all means, then, keep using the `apa6` document class, just without the `man` option. Separately, do create "short" rather than "long' equations...